# Drarry fan fiction where the Malfoys hide the fact they are Veelas from Draco

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I once read the description of a Drarry fan fic I didn't like at the time. I never had a chance to read it. It was about Veelas and stuff. The description was something like this:

"What if some of the Malfoys hid the fact they were Veelas from Draco? You end up with a very confused Draco Malfoy wondering why he is in love with Harry Potter."

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? Do you remember what site it might have been on? If so you can [edit] that information in to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly [*The Veela Enigma*](http://archive.skyehawke.com/story.php?no=7142&chapter=1) by jennavere, hosted on skyehawke.com (warning: apparently it's rated R/ NC17 for adult language and situations).

> **Summary:** What if some of Draco's ancestors, pretending to be pureblood, concealed the truth about their veela heritage? You'd end up with one very confused Draco Malfoy, who's fallen head over heels in love with Harry Potter and has no idea why. A Harry/Draco Romance.

---

Found with the Google query `veela "very confused draco"` which yields [this Tumblr post](http://itsdrarrydarling.tumblr.com/post/148004470980/could-you-rec-any-good-jealousdraco-drarry-fics) listing the fanfic.